# Error calling CREATE_JOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, procedure

I have the following error in PL/SQL. I am not able to know what the error is. Please help me.

```
SQL> BEGIN
2  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
3  (
4  JOB_NAME => 'TESTINGFILE'
5  ,COMMENTS =>'TEST'
6  );
7  END;
8  /

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: I believe you should use all the parameters like enabled, job type, start etc., I am not much familiar with these but it looks like it...

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`DBMS_Scheduler.Create_Job` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000363), the procedure requires the `job_name`, `job_type` and `job_action` parameters. You've only specified `job_name` so you need to define the other two.

You can find `DBMS_Scheduler.Create_Job` examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm), [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_scheduler_examples.htm), and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I'm new to scheduling jobs but I came across this post while I was troubleshooting mine so I figured it would be good to share once I worked it out.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => 'NAME_OF_PROCEDURE_JOB',
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'NAME_OF_PROCEDURE',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=30;',
        start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, 
        enabled => TRUE,
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        comments => 'Schedules a job to run NAME_OF_PROCEDURE at 11:30 everyday'
        );
END;
```